# Execute Batch with only one query?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

**My General Question is**: Is it inefficient/bad practice to call `preparedStatement.executeBatch()` if there's only one query in the batch?

I'm writing a generic method for the [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper) to execute a query. There's a javabean called `HelperQuery` which holds a list of arrays another javabean called `QueryParameter` which holds a type (like `STRING`, `BLOB`, `INT`, etc.) and a value. The `QueryParameter` is used to fill the `HelperQuery`'s `PreparedStatement`. In many cases, there will be only one array of `QueryParameter`s.

**My Specific Question is**: Should I handle things differently if there's only one array of `QueryParameter`s or would it be ok to handle things exactly the same regardless of how many `QueryParameter`s there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`executeBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) is a "`super`" method from the `PreparedStatement`'s parent `Statement` which returns an `int[]` which indicates the success/failure of the executed queries and [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) returns a `ResultSet`. Therefore, it would be a good idea to have the two be totally different method calls so the developer can handle them differently. I would recommend:

1. An `executeQuery(HelperQuery helperQuery)` method which will return the associated `ResultSet` and will only get the first `QueryParameter`s from the `HelperQuery` (for convenience) and another method which the developer can specify which `QueryParameter` set to use (either have them specify a number of the `QueryParameter` list or just pass in the `QueryParameter`s explicitly (I recommend the second of the two)).
2. An `executeBatch(HelperQuery helperQuery` method which will return the `int[]` and the developer can handle that as they wish.

It's always good to give the user (developer in this case) power to do what they want (but also provide for a simple solution for them to perform common tasks).

Comment: Realized the answer as I was generating the code for the question.